# PowerShell convert from name

Tags: bash, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have on a file multiple names,

```
Mario Rossi
John Doe Michael
Mario De Rossi
Mario D'Rossi
```

I would like to convert them in this format with PowerShell.

```
Mario,Rossi,"Mario Rossi [External]",m.rossi,m.rossi_ext@mydomain.com,$TRUE
John,"Doe Michael","John Doe Michael [External]",j.michael,j.michael_ext@mydomain.com,$TRUE
Mario,"De Rossi","Mario De Rossi [External]",m.derossi,m.derossi_ext@mydomain.com,$TRUE
Mario,"D'Rossi","Mario D'Rossi [External]",m.drossi,m.drossi@mydomain.com,$TRUE
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: i don't know how to do it automatically, so every time i do it manually, which is really hard. can you help?Thanks.

Comment: @m0b1l3us3r You just need to formulate formal rules how to convert name to other things and write the code to apply that rules. Currently, I see the following problems: `John Doe Michael` -> `j.michael_ext` why `Doe` not the part of email? `Mario D'Rossi` -> `m.drossi` why no `_ext` in email?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try Something like this

```
Get-Content "C:\temp\StartFile.txt" | 
%{
  $Words=$_ -split ' '
  $FisrtName=$Words[0]
  $LastName= ($Words[1..($Words.Length -1)] -join ' ')
  $LastNameFormated=$LastName.ToLower().Replace(" ", "").Replace("'", "")
  '{0},"{1}","{0} {1} [External]",{2}.{3},{2}.{3}_ext@mydomain.com,$TRUE' -f $FisrtName, $LastName, $FisrtName.ToLower().Substring(0, 1), $LastNameFormated  
} | Out-File "C:\temp\EndFile.txt"
```

Comment: Exactly what i wanted,
Thanks a lot
Regards.